# CakePHP 3.x How to clear cache for views using console?

Tags: bash, cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

My CakePHP 3.x app is hosted in bitbucket.

I have a deploy script that will git clone to a folder that uses timestamp as folder name.

After which the script will then create symlink `/var/virtual/webapp/current` to this timestamped folder.

However, for some reason, the view files are still cached despite this newly deployed folder. Also the `tmp` folder is empty.

How do I clear cache for view files using the console, so I can add it into the bash script?

```
'Cache' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'path' => CACHE,
        ],

        /**
         * Configure the cache used for general framework caching. Path information,
         * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this
         * configuration.
         */
        '_cake_core_' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_core_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+2 minutes',
        ],

        /**
         * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache
         * configuration is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings
         * in connections.
         */
        '_cake_model_' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+2 minutes',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: What cache engine are you using?

Comment: what path did you set for saving the files when configuring the cache?

Comment: See above. I think you mean CACHE?

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
// Clear one cache config
bin/cake cache clear <configname>

// Clear all cache configs
bin/cake cache clear_all
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use next command to clear **all** cache via console:
bin/cake console Cake\Cache\Cache::clear(false)

[CakePHP: Clearing Cached Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#clearing-cached-data)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to clear the cache from the console?

[Clearing Cache in Cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#clearing-cached-data)

Does the below not work for you?

```
// Will only clear expired keys.
Cache::clear(true);

// Will clear all keys.
Cache::clear(false);
```

You could create a shell script and could put it there.

[Shells and Console](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html)

**Or just delete all the files in the folder you specified for cache with rm...**

```
rm -f /path/to/my/cached/files/*
```

P.S.

- This does not cover anything cached via php opcache. Is that enabled? That could also be what is caching the view files
- There is also the potential that your script isn't actually updating the symlink to the current directory?